# How to make a card group with one column in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

I have several cards in a card group in Bootstrap 5, and by default they are all placed in the same row.

How can I make each card occupy 100% of the width and have them laid out in a column?

My code looks like this (react-bootstrap but surely should be the same with normal Bootstrap):

```
<CardGroup>
  <Card>...</Card>
  <Card>...</Card>
  <Card>...</Card>
</CardGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your Cards like:

```
<div class="card-group">
    <div class="row row-cols-1 g-4">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card">...</div>
            <div class="card">...</div>
            <div class="card">...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The 'row-cols-1' will put the cards in a single column.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately this didn't work. Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/vewfky35/6/. The cards still have individual borders & corners instead of being glued together like the example without row&col.

Comment: If you add `border-0` to the card div class does that give you what you want?

Comment: No, then the borders just disappear altogether.